# Two UITableViews with different CustomCells (one for table1 and the second for table2)

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell

i try to implement 2 UITableViews on my view. Both tables have different custom-cells (Table one has customcell one and table two has customcell table.

My cellForRowAtIndexPath don't handle it

```
if (tableView == self.firstTableView)
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier.....


return cell;

}

else if (tableView == self.secondTableView)
{
 tatic NSString *CellIdentifier.....


return cell;
}
```

How can i handle my problem ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Have individual UITableviewControllers for each table view so that data source is handled separately and that is the right design approach.

Say you have two tableviews.

Set tableview1 delegate to UITableviewController1

Set tableview2 delegate to UITableviewController2

Bharath

Comment: Hi, how to delegate it different ? I think my solution with tableview == self.<tablename> is this kind of different delegation ?

Comment: Please check this project https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/TwoTableview. I think this is what you need. I have used single view controller as you wanted to delegate different data sources.